# Unable to resolve dependencies. 'jQuery 2.1.4' is not compatible with 'bootstrap 3.3.6 constraint: jQuery (≥ 1.9.1 && < 3.0.0)'

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to add "jQuery.UI.Theme.Redmond" in my ASP.NET web forms application through Nuget Package Manager but, I am seeing the following error,

[image]

I am having latest boostrap (3.3.6), jquery (2.1.4) in my ASP.NET Web forms project.

I appreciate any suggestion on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Downgrade the version of jQuery to something less than 2.0.0 and more than 1.6.0. You can do this by going to *Tools/NuGet Package Manager/Manage NuGet packages for Solution/*.

Now go to Installed tab and search for jQuery. Then on the right side change the version as described above and click Install.

Comment: then you would come across situation where other libraries which are using upgraded  version of Jquery will though errors.then why don't you like to use bootstrap date piker instead of using old one ... :)

Answer (score 1):

if you have downloaded the packages and select them locally for installation, you need to download all the required Dependencies and copy them to your local nuGet packages path.
about bootstrap Version = 4.5.2, as you can see  dependencies:

jQuery (> = 3.0.0 && <4.0.0)
popper.js (> = 1.16.1 && <2.0.0)

https://www.nuget.org/packages/bootstrap/4.5.2#

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error your are getting,
JQuery.UI.Theme.Redmond 1.10.3 requires jQuery version of 1.6.0 and upward && less than jQuery version 2.0.0

You have jquery (2.1.4) installed which is why you are getting the error because  the version installed is over the jQuery 2.0.0 limit

you will need to decrease the version of the installed jQuery to a version not up to version 2.0.0 if you really want to use the theme